# Pushing references to the bottom of the page

Tags: bibliographies, page-breaking

I'm new to LaTeX and I have a two fold question, but first, this is the header that I'm using:

```
\documentclass[aps,pre,preprint]{revtex4}
\usepackage{graphicx,amssymb,multirow,amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\bibliographystyle{apsrev}
\newcommand{\mb}{\mathbf}
\newcommand{\mc}{\mathcal}
\newcommand{\eps}{\varepsilon}
\newcommand{\pd}[2]{\frac{\partial#1}{\partial#2}}
\newcommand{\comment}[1]{}
```

Now, I have a couple of figures in my paper, and for convenience, I just placed all of the figures at the bottom. After the figures, I placed a `\pagebreak`, and then I placed my `\bibliography`. However, for some reason, the bibliography is coming before a certain figure. Furthermore, there's this partial line above the bibliography.

Is it possible to: 1) remove this line, and 2) place the bibliography on the last page, separated from everything else by a `\pagebreak`?

Comment: You should use `\clearpage` instead of `\pagebreak`, since there could be figures that still need to be flushed (perhaps the last one), which may be bigger than normal. Perhaps this also takes care of your first concern.

Comment: @Werner  Yes, it also take care of footnotes, since `\clearpage` calls `\newpage`, which calls `\vfil`, and `\pagebreak` does not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `\newpage` or `\clearpage` instead of `\pagebreak`:  the former commands have internal call to `\vfill`, which pushes footnotes to the bottom, while the latter command does not have it.